# dbManager class returning unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am trying to code a php forum OOP style and I am having abit of difficulty this is the first time I have coded OOP style and I keep getting the error

> unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 5

here is my code

```
<?php
class dbManager{
  var $MySQL_Conx;
  var $details = configManager::getConfig;
  var $mysqli = $this->dbConnect();
  public function dbSelect($sql, $mysqli){

  }
  private function dbConnect(){
    $this->CloseConnection()
    $this->MySQL_Conx = mysqli_connect($this->details['dbhost'], $this->details['dbuser'], $this->details['dbpass'], $this->details['dbdatabase'])
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
    } else {
      return $MySQL_Conx;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

also `configManager::getConfig;` returns an array of all the details to connect to the database.

Comment: Put a semi-colon at the end of `$this->MySQL_Conx = mysqli_connect...`

Comment: just did that same error :/ @fred-ii

Comment: what version of PHP are you using

Comment: You forgot one in `$this->CloseConnection()` also @user2710382

Comment: Are you even aware that PHP 5.0 was released some time ago ... like, 10 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please assign the values in constructor

```
<?php
class dbManager{
  var $MySQL_Conx;
  var $details = array();
  var $mysqli = '';
  //you have to assign the values in the constructor
  public function __construct()
  {
    //assign the details
    $this->details = configManager::getConfig;
    //assign the mysql connection
    $this->mysqli = $this->dbConnect()
  }

  public function dbSelect($sql, $mysqli){

  }
  private function dbConnect(){
    $this->CloseConnection()
    $this->MySQL_Conx = mysqli_connect($this->details['dbhost'], $this->details['dbuser'], $this->details['dbpass'], $this->details['dbdatabase']);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
    } else {
      return $MySQL_Conx;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the initializations on the `constructor`. The comments inside the code indicate the mistakes you had done.

From the PHP Manual

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

#### The fixed code...

```
<?php
class dbManager{
    var $MySQL_Conx;
    var $details; 
    var $mysqli; 

    function __construct()   //<---- Wrapped them in a constructor
    {
        $this->details=configManager::getConfig;
        $this->mysqli=$this->dbConnect();
    }

    public function dbSelect($sql, $mysqli){

    }
    private function dbConnect(){
        $this->CloseConnection();   //<--- You forgot a semicolon
    $this->MySQL_Conx = mysqli_connect($this->details['dbhost'], $this->details['dbuser'], $this->details['dbpass'], $this->details['dbdatabase']);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    } else {
        return $this->MySQL_Conx; //<---- Added this keyword
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Missing the semi-colon at the end of `$this->MySQL_Conx = mysqli_connect...` ;-)

Comment: That's one of the missing ones lol there was two missing actually. I missed the first one.

Comment: Sidenote, I would make those properties `private`, or better yet `protected`

Comment: Yeah .. I had mentioned everything in the code comments :) Please see if I had missed anything mate @Fred-ii-

Comment: The other is in `$this->MySQL_Conx = mysqli_connect($this->details['dbhost'], .........`

Comment: I added the semi-colon ;-)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: @PeeHaa, Initializing things under `constructor` a bad practice ? I don't know why the **downvote** rage ? :)

Comment: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/